# How merge two objects in another

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have first object

```
obj1 = {lastName: "", address1: "Some address"}
```

and second object:

```
obj2 = {lastName: "Salivan", address1: "1200 Getty Center Dr"}
```

in the result object:

```
obj3 = {lastName: "Salivan", address1: "Some address"}
```

Comment: You haven't indicated any way to determine which object to prefer if a given property is in both. Nor have you provided any code that attempts to solve this (which you should always do before posting to Stack Overflow).

Comment: Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for me would be to do the following:

```
const newObject = {
    ...obj1,
    ...obj2,
}
```

The thing is, it will override your values! So better not merge two similar objects into one, usually it is used to update values of an object or merge different objects into one.

As `@AlexSp3` suggested, you can also:

```
obj3 = Object.assign(obj1, obj2)
```

For your specific case:

```
const obj3 = {
   key1: '',
   key2: '',
}
if (!obj1.key1) {
   obj3.key1 = obj2.key1;
} else {
   obj3.key1 = obj1.key1;
}

// ... repeat with key2
```

Comment: it returns second object

Comment: `obj3 = Object.assign(obj1, obj2)` does the same work, maybe you can add it to the answer

Comment: Of course, your keys get updated to the latest object you pass.....

Comment: Always difficult to answer a question when you don't know the requirements.

Comment: its not correct. I need return obj2 value if in obj1 includes empty value

Comment: Really you need help with that? a simpe if()  will work for you

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to select the non falsey values...

```js
let obj1 = {
  lastName: "",
  address1: "Some address"
}
let obj2 = {
  lastName: "Salivan",
  address1: "1200 Getty Center Dr"
}

let result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj1).map(([key, value]) => {
    return [key, value || obj2[key]]
  })
);


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without overwriting values:

```js
const obj1 = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2
}

const obj2 = {
  key2: 3,
  key3: 4
}

function mergeObjects(obj0, obj1) {
  // merge object keys into array
  const joined = [...Object.keys(obj0), ...Object.keys(obj1)]

  // remove duplicates
  const uniqueKeys = [...new Set(joined)]

  // merge obj0 and obj1 into new Object
  // obj1 overrides obj0
  const newObject = {}
  uniqueKeys.forEach(key => {
      if (obj0[key] !== undefined && obj1[key] !== undefined) {
          newObject[key] = [obj0[key], obj1[key]]
      } else if (obj0[key] === undefined && obj1[key] !== undefined) {
          newObject[key] = obj1[key]
      } else if (obj0[key] !== undefined && obj1[key] === undefined) {
          newObject[key] = obj0[key]
      } else {
          console.log('OBJECT MERGING ERROR')
      }
  })
  return newObject
}

console.log(mergeObjects(obj1, obj2))
```